# Runtime DNS Entry of Server Ip in Domain Providers

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, nginx, google-cloud-platform, dns

I had an infrastructure consist of load balancer(nginx configuration) and two servers,
one is for UK and other is US,
Now requirements are I have to deploy runtime application to one of these servers based on client ip, that part is done in nginx conf with geoip module.
and will do server entry as well if not available in nginx upstream list.

Now second part is these servers e.g UK US having an ip's, I want runtime DNS entries for them as well,

Servers can be of AWS,Azure,GCP their domain providers may vary,

So its possible to do DNS entry during deployment stage like first application will be deployed to corresponding server then that server should do entry as well in DNS and get domain name (should be provided by user in runtime).

in short, there is script which is doing runtime domain entries like as.blabla.com in nginx
but I need to have an another parameter for server like 190.80.0.13  for asia, and i want dns entry for this ip as well either this belong to GCP,AWS or any DNS related system.

Question may seem alot twisted, its okay we can discuss further.

Comment: Are you using one Nginx load balancer and directing traffic to the US and UK? You want the load balancer to make DNS queries on each client's IP address? Geolocation in Nginx? Your system will be slow, fragile, and hard to maintain.

Comment: Please let me know whether you are  attempting to do a URL mapping to back end services using geo origin headers?

Answer (score 0):

In AWS you will be better with AWS Elastic Load Balancer and Route53, using Geolocation, or Geoproximity as routing policy.
For better performance you can add (CDN) Cloudfront distribution.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-elb-load-balancer.html